# Word 2019 StyleRef partially appearing

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have a word document (.docx) which makes extensive use of StyleRefs to display the current Chapter and Pagenumber on top of every page. Since this afternoon the StyleRefs on some Pages are glitching out and are displaying in addition to their normal content also some parts of the StyleRef.

[Example for Wrong Heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiEVc.png)

[Another Example for wrong Heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ChcL.png)

I have encountered this behaviour before, but back then the glitching StyleRefs could be turned back into their proper Form with ALT + F9. I have also tried this particular document on another PC with Word 2016 installed and there the Headings are displayed correctly. I have also look in the Options of Word if i have mayhaps enabled the Option to show Field Functions instead of their values, but this option is still unticked. To be honest i am completly at a loss here and would really appreciate any help with this.

[Word Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWG9U.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is a recent bug that has been fixed. You need to get the latest update.

Check your build number. In the Windows version you can see this under File > Account > About Word.

Refer to [Suzanne Barnhill's answer in this Word Answers thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-2019-field-within-table-within-header-not/536f0630-5442-4e44-bca1-db2f8fdf5457) this morning.

> The report from Microsoft is: ""We found the source of the issue and
> it should be mitigated for Word **Win32** builds > 16.0.13625.20000 and
> Word **Mac** builds > 16.45.20122501. It may take up to 24 hours for users
> to receive the change. If they are still experiencing the issue after
> that time, they should restart Word and Office and it should resolve."

See also this [later message](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/text-being-cut-off-in-styleref-field-within-header/ecca0065-7d24-45c6-8feb-6f1d60f73644?LastReply=true#LastReply) from MVP Doug Robbins...

> The team found there was another flight that needed to be pulled to fix
> the bug. We have verified the issue is mitigated. Same as with the
> previous, it may take up to 24 hours for users to receive the rollout.
> If users are still hitting the issue, they will need to close out of
> Word and Office for the rollout to take effect. Thanks again for
> keeping us updated on the issue.

### This should be temporary. There is a workaround that seems to work.

The workaround is to place a couple of spaces after the [StyleRef field](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF).